# Telepathic creature VOX

Tags: creature-vocalizations

Name a non-human character from a film who talks in english telepathically but emits(speaks) no additional languages. I can't think of one.

Also, list a few of your favorite "scary" creature vocals(language based) in a film.

Answer (score 1):

The aliens in Independence Day speak through others telepathically. There are a few others that are on the tip of my tongue, but I can't quite place them.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, the interstellar navigators from the Original Dune movie lived in tanks and spoke thru some speaker device.

Answer (score 0):

The encounter in the end of the last act in *Contact* immediately comes to mind.

Scary language-based creature vocals? Something tells me there was a thread on this a long time ago, but my faves would have to be girl in *The Exorcist*, the beheaded Ashe from *Alien*, Jabba the Hutt, and maybe even Darth Vader (notable for being the only voice of the Sith lords that didn't just sound horribly forced - there were some nice ideas for Darth Sidious, but the voice acting ruined its cohesion).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite monster telepathy, but David Cronenberg's 1981 classic *Scanners* has some great scenes involving telepathy. It's not so much about communication but more controlling others via telepathy. It's also got the famous head-explosion scene. Worth a watch for that scene alone!

Answer (score 0):

Unicron from the animated Transformers film spoke to Megatron/Galvatron telepathically - although as a bunch of robots not sure if it counts as telepathy?  Also at times it's not really clear if he's speaking direct or via his evil robot brain. Hm, controversial.

Favourite monster noises:

- Predator, of course.
- The ghosts from the American version of The Grudge. Haven't seen the Japanese original yet, don't hate me.  Do they use similar noises out of interest?
- The things in the subway tunnel in Cloverfield
- To agree with NoiseJockey, the demon from The Exorcist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, These are all great!

Jake